# Which sex is homogametic in side-blotched lizards?

Tags: chromosome, reptile, sex-chromosome, gamete

I'm just trying to find out whether the male side-blotched lizard is the hetero- or homogametic sex in side-blotched lizards (*Uta stansburiana*) - some reptiles are ZW system (female heterogamete) and some are XY (male heterogamete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lizards of the genus *Uta* are apparently male heterogametic (XY) ([Pennock et al. 1969)](http://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/130018). The XY system seems to be the most common mode of sex determination in iguanid lizards ([Kasahara et al. 1983](http://aerg.canberra.edu.au/library/sex_general/1983_Kasahara_etal.pdf)).

> Kasahara, Y et al. 1983. Chromosome mechanisms of sex determination, G- and C-band patterns and nucleolus organizer regions in *Tropidurus torquatus* (Sauria, Iguanidae).  Genetica 60: 151-156.
>
> Pennock, L.A. et al. 1969. Minute Y chromosome in the lizard genus *Uta* (Family Iguanidae). Cytogenetics and Genome Research 8: 9-19.